# Is the set $\{ x\in G | x^{-1}ax=a\}$ is a subgroup of $G$ for any $a\in G$ (where $G$ is a group)?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $G$ is a group of size $n$.

Is it correct that for any $a\in G$ the set $H = \{ x\in G | x^{-1}ax=a\}$ is a subgroup of $G$?

I tried hard but I couldn't find a counter-example so I assume it's correct.

In order to show that this set is a subgroup of $G$ I have to show the following :

1. $1_G \in H$
2. H is closed under the operator of $G$, that is $\forall x,y\in H \ : \ xy\in H.$
3. H contains an inverse, that is $\forall x\in H \ : \ x^{-1}\in H.$

I already showed that $1_G\in H$ - It is very simple to show it from the definition of $H$.

I'm not sure how to show the other two. For example this is what I did already while trying to prove the (2) condition but got stuck:

$\ \ \  $Let $x,y\in H$ then there exist $a,b\in G$ such that $x^{-1}ax = a$
and $y^{-1}by= b$.

How can I continue from here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's true. The set $H = \{x \in G\ |\ x^{-1}ax = a\}$ is called the **centralizer** of $a$ in $G$, often denoted $C_G(a)$. Since $x^{-1}ax = a$ if and only if $ax = xa$, we see that $C_G(a)$ contains precisely the elements of $G$ which commute with $a$.

To show item 2: Note that $(xy)^{-1} = y^{-1}x^{-1}$, so $(xy)^{-1}a(xy) = y^{-1}x^{-1}axy = y^{-1}(x^{-1}ax)y$. Do you see what to do now?

For item 3, if $x^{-1}ax = a$, try multiplying on the left and right so that the left hand side becomes $a$.

Comment: Why do you mention $(xy)^{-1}$ for the (2) proof? I'm trying to understand that.

Comment: @SyndicatorBBB: We want to show that if $x \in H$ and $y \in H$ then $xy \in H$. The condition $xy \in H$ is equivalent to $(xy)^{-1}a(xy) = a$. (Just replace $x$ with $xy$ in the definition of $H$.)

Comment: Yes. $x^{-1}ax = a$ and then we get $y^{-1}ay$ which is also $a$ and we proved that $xy\in H$.

Comment: I'm trying to show the third item now.

Comment: Then I get $a=xax^{-1}$, correct?

Comment: @SyndicatorBBB: That's right. Do you see what $a = xax^{-1}$ implies about $x$?

Comment: It's so confusing... let me think about it for a moment.

Comment: Oh, It means that $(x^{-1}ax)^{-1} =xax^{-1}= a $ and therefore $x^{-1}ax\in H$ ?

Comment: @SyndicatorBBB: No. It's simpler than that. Remember that the goal is to show that $x^{-1} \in H$. By the definition of $H$, this means you need to show that $(x^{-1})^{-1}a(x^{-1}) = a$. Can you simplify $(x^{-1})^{-1}$?

Comment: Yes :) Thank you very very much !!!

Answer (score 3):

Note that $H$ is defined for a *fixed* $a \in G$.  So, we should write

> Let $x,y \in H$.  Then $x^{-1}ax = a$ and $y^{-1}ay = a$.

Now, can you prove $xy \in H$?

---

It might help to describe $H$ as follows:

> For a fixed $a \in G$, we define $H_a$ to be the set $\{x \in G:x^{-1}ax = a\}$.

Comment: Hmm let me know if I understand correctly. From what you wrote $x$ must be equal to $y$ and therefore we get that $xy=x$ and as we know $x\in H$ ?

Comment: How did you decide that $x = y$?

Comment: because $x^{-1}ax = a$ and $y^{-1}ay = a$. Can't we derive from this that $x=y$?

Comment: Absolutely not!  What if $a = e$ (for example)?

Comment: Oh you are correct. Silly mistake...

Comment: $xy$ = $x^{-1}axy^{-1}ay$ = $a^2$. That's what I know. And I don't know if $a\in H$.

Comment: That is also incorrect.  Try starting from $(xy)^{-1}a(xy)$.  And yes, $a$ is necessarily in $H$, as you can verify.

Comment: Oh I understand.. Exactly as @Bugno noted...

Comment: I understand now. Thank you very much @Omnomnomnom!